# Swift - JSON Serialisation of an optional property

Tags: ios, json, swift, serialization

I have a object that is created from JSON (serialised). This object has an optional property. When this optional property is empty, the server doesn't send the property's key in the payload. What is the correct way to handle these types of scenarios (with regards to error handling)?

`imageURL` is optional. Which means sometimes `profileImgPath` doesn't exist in the JSON

```
import UIKit


class Person: Codable {
    let firstName: String
    let lastName: String
    let imageURL: URL?
    let id: String

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case firstName
        case lastName
        case imageURL = "profileImgPath"
        case id = "_id"
    }

    init(id: String, firstName: String, lastName: String, imageURL:URL) {
        self.id = id
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
        self.imageURL = imageURL
    }

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.id = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .id)
        self.firstName = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .firstName)
        self.lastName = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .lastName)
        self.imageURL = try? values.decode(URL.self, forKey: .imageURL)
    }
}

struct PersonsList : Codable {
    let persons: [Person]
}
```

**Serialization**

```
let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: JSON, options: [])
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let patientList = try! decoder.decode(PatientsList.self, from: jsonData)
```

I am getting this error:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error:
>   Swift.DecodingError.keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue:
>   "profileImgPath", intValue: nil),
>   Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue:
>   "patients", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue:
>   0)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key
>   CodingKeys(stringValue: \"profileImgPath\", intValue: nil)
>   (\"profileImgPath\").", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: 1. Make `Person` a `struct` then you can remove both `init` functions. 2. If `imageURL` is optional, make it optional. `let imageURL: URL?`. 3. Make `Person` conform to `Codable`.

Comment: @rmaddy Person is a Superclass, with 2 subclasses. Structs cannot have inheritance.

Comment: OK then ignore my first point. The other two still apply.

Comment: Just make this property optional as `let imageURL: URL?`

Comment: @rmaddy I've updated my question and code with your suggestions. But I am still getting an error (added it as well)

Comment: @Kamran I've made this change but I am still getting an error (added it in the question)

Comment: here you have to decode it as optional. `self.imageURL = try? values.decode(URL.self, forKey: .imageURL)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's easy.

Use decodeIfPresent

```
self.imageURL = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: . imageURL)
```